# How can you go about creating a csv file from an empty Dataset<Row> in spark 2.1 with headers

Tags: apache-spark

Spark 2.1 has default behaviour of writing empty files while creating a CSV from a Dataset

How can you go about creating a csv file with headers ?
This is what i am using to write the file

```
dataFrame.repartition(NUM_PARTITIONS).write()
              .option("header", "true")
              .option("delimiter", "\t")
              .option("overwrite", "true")
              .option("nullValue", "null")
              .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
              .csv("some/path");
```

Comment: Could you please share a snippet of how you create the DataFrame?

Comment: So basically, im migrating from spark 1.5 where we used Spark-CSV package to default Spark2.1 api. Previously the headers were being created whereas now its not. You can assume the dataframe was created from a file with a schema.